# getting the button enable or disable if the radio button is checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to Enable a button in html if the radio button is checked. this is to be done dynamically as if the radio button gets unchecked the button should also get disabled automatically. is there any possible way to do this using javascript or Jquery..code should should be in php

Comment: Please review [ask] to learn what should be included in a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't uncheck a radio button, but if you want to do it on a checkbox, here is a suggestion using jquery:

```
   $("#checkBoxID").on("change", function(e) {
    $("#buttonID").prop("disabled",!$("#checkBoxID").is(":checked"));
  });
```

This will set the disabled attribute on the button to the opposite of the checked attribute.

•Box Checked? Disabled Attribute on button set to false

•Box unchecked? Disabled attribute on button set to true

Updates dynamically as the checkbox is selected.

-- edit --

[Here is a link to a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/D_Lux/0tcoxyq8/) of this working as described and requested.

Comment: I dont want to uncheck the radio button but i just want to enable a normal button if a radio button is checked.. is this possible using jquery???

Comment: Your question asked for the button to dynamically be enabled or disabled when the radio button was checked or unchecked. I was merely trying to answer your question. Regardless, it should work the same.